# Where can I get good books / pdfs on Mira bai?

Tags: bhakti, book-recommendation

I wanted to read the life of Mira bai written by a devotee and not a historian who will try to cross verify whether the facts mentions are true or not. Poems are available online but a devotional book on Mira bai that will kindle ones devotion was what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Buy Panduranga Vijayam aka maha bhaktha vijayam from Lifco publications Tamilnadu. It consists of accounts of Several Maharastra Devotees of Vittala and also includes mirabai kabirdas badrachachala Ramadasr.  It was compiled by omniscient Nabhaji Daasar