# Did Meerabai and Sai baba meet?

Tags: sai

I was just watching a movie about sai baba and the showed that Meera bai(Shree Krishna Devotee) met sai baba when he was at shirdi . Is this true and how old is this history?  Is this during the time where technology had already evolved well that history could be well documented?

Comment: Well both entities existed centuries apart, how can they meet?

Comment: She might not be Meera Bai, but Radhakrishna Mai, a devotee of Sai baba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meera bai lived between 1498- 1546. Sai Baba was from late 19th century and early 20th century. Obviously they didn't meet.

There is a devotee of Krishna named Sundari bai Kshirsagar who was travelling many pilgrimages in India and reached Shirdi. She became to Shirdi with a statue of Radha Krishna. Hence she was named as Radhakrishna mai by Sai Baba. Her attire in the movie is similar to Mirabai. You might have got confused between the two.

See [Radhakrishna mai coming to Sai Baba in Shirdi](https://saisatcharitraparayana.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/radhakrishna-mai-coming-to-sai-baba-in-shirdi/amp).

Comment: @Sarvobhouma, you're absolutely correct, I did hear RadhaKrishna mai but thought that was the name given by locals to Meera bai. I am very curious about Meera bai's story not much of it is in google or the internet. There was story based on her on NDTV Imagine but that's also nowhere to be found now. Is her life history well recorded in any scriptures or something?

Comment: @juztcode There are many stories of Meera Bai. You are right that not much information is present on the internet about Meera bai to read online but there are many biographies and books written on her. See this question.[Where can I get good books / pdfs on Mira bai?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37180/5212). There are some pdf and articles too.

Comment: I'll delete this comment if it violates any rules, but if you're in India, do you think there are any retailer/online sites that you could buy "Meera bai's" dvd that was given by NDTV imagine?[reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meera_(2009_TV_series)), [and here](https://youtu.be/2ib0FdAycP8)